# What is the difference between Commercial and Industrial temperature range IC physical parts?

Tags: packages

If I buy the Industrial and Commercial variants of the same IC, besides the markings what differences are there in the actual parts?

Seems like they must use the same die, so is it different formations in the packaging material?  Different types of bond-out wires?

Or is it a matter of binning where the higher grade parts have been tested and found to work at the wider temperature range?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the temperature range of industrial and military products so high?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/236850/why-is-the-temperature-range-of-industrial-and-military-products-so-high)

Comment: @MarcusMüller This question is about the actual *difference* between the ICs. Basically, how do you make a high-temperature IC.

Comment: @pipe true! I should have just pointed out that the comments under the answers contain some interesting info.

Comment: In some cases the difference between the parts may be zero.  Industrial spec parts are tested to a higher standard. Depending on the test yield the commercial parts may have failed the higher standard test or not tested in which case they could be good enough to be industrial grade but are not guaranteed to be.

Comment: Bonding inside the IC comes to mind, as well as plastic type.

Answer (score 3):

Parts are tested after production to ensure that they meet the datasheet specifications.

Commercial parts are those that meet the datasheet at commercial temperature but failed at the industrial temperature.

Industrial parts are those that meet the datasheet at industrial range but failed at the automotive/military range.

Comment: Not really. Design for automotive/mil grade requires a different IC layout approach, via policy, and better design/verification. If you design for automotive/space-grade specifications but got a bunch of commercial-grade stuff instead, in commercial quantities, this design engineering sucks.

Comment: There are lots of differences between commercial, industrial, automotive and military. Some are downtown the associated traceability but must are on the datasheet and the governing factor whether a die becomes commercial or industrial is whether it operates at the required design points

Answer (score 3):

If a part is offered in both industrial and commercial grades, it is possible that the commercial parts are dropouts from testing to industrial grade.

However, it depends on relative volume of both grades, as dictated by customer demands.

Making industrial-grade ICs requires tighter design to accommodate wider process corners and use of more expensive foundry libraries, and fabbing also cost more. It also requires more conservative layout technique, wider interconnect, double vias, etc. To achieve good integration, a foundry usually offers a [set of standard cell libraries](http://www.europractice-ic.com/libraries_TSMC.php) for every taste, but the cost differs as well.

If majority of customers for a particular IC demand industrial grade, the IC will be designed and fabricated as such, and test dropouts would sold as commercial ICs.

Getting to industrial grade might also include a change in IC packaging, to use, for example, a metal-ceramic instead of plastic.

However, if the volume for commercial grades is high, the die can be taped out with less expensive libraries and manufactured by less expensive variant of the fab process, so save on cost and maximize gross margins. Then the same functional IC will come from different wafers for different grades, and will go through a different set of testings.

Answer (score 2):

Design for higher temperatures is more of a pain because of more device param variation away from nominal.

FETs transconductance is lower, thus more W/L is needed (more area, higher die cost).

Leakage currents will be higher, thus larger sample-hold capacitors are needed in the ADCs or elsewhere.

Given certain headrooms, with operating conditions of transistors (bipolars and FETs), some circuit topologies become impossible and other topologies are invented.

Then you can examine the down-well rock-logging circuits of Schlumberger, at 400 degree.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the difference is in where on the wafer the chip was. In the center, where image (of photolithography) is most accurate, it's wider range, better yield, faster switching (for CPU and memory). On contrary, edges are slower and go for commercial range.

Comment: Hmm, I doubt that this is true. Wafers are stepped (search: wafer stepper) when the pattern is projected so the same pattern is projected multiple times in a tile pattern. So there can be no "advantage" in the middle of the wafer. Dies are just fabricated and then tested for performance, see JonRB's answer.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie hm, might still be that especially for smaller dies, the single step is a multi-die step, and that the mask simply isn't as sharply projected everywhere. but yeah, this all ends up being tested and bin'ed.

Comment: Last time i heard this story from a zynq salesman.

Comment: *might still be that especially for smaller dies* No, any modern IC manufacturing process. They have to, masks (the "negatives") can only be a certain size, less sharpness at the edges is one resoan for that. For large ICs one reticle (one mask projection) could hold the pattern of only a few chips but for small ICs hundreds of chips per mask is possible.

Comment: On modern 300mm wafers it can only be economical to make many dies in one go so the mask pattern (reticle) must be repeated. I never pay much attention to what sales ppl say when technical details are involved. If they knew it well they would not work in sales.

Comment: You are generally correct, but there are two kinds of sales, one requires expertise. Which kind is this guy i am not sure.