# Choosing industrial grade components after a consumer grade proof of concept

Tags: microcontroller, pcb-fabrication, industrial

I assembled a basic prototype with an ATSAMD21G18 based microcontroller and what I believe are consumer grade sensors (LSM6DSOX, LIS3MDL) to test out a proof of concept for product that would need to operate in an industrial scenario where the main factors are temperature and vibration. What are the major considerations necessary when looking to graduate from a simple idea into industrial grade components and PCB's?

Comment: not really a duplicate, but I think the reasons given in my answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/236850/why-is-the-temperature-range-of-industrial-and-military-products-so-high/236854#236854) highlight a few things why people choose industrial-grade components, and that might help you narrow this down.

Answer (score 2):

They're perfectly acceptable parts provided you use them within the specs. They don't know if they're in a consumer or industrial thing.

Check the temperature rating, make sure your PCBs have ULV0 fire retardant, correct creepage and clearances, fuses if necessary... Refer to iec61010 for lab devices. Be more specific about the industry. If it's automotive you'll want AEC parts, medical... 60601 is the standard etc. If you're actually planning on selling these, best invest in a copy of the relevant standard...