# What design changes are made for automotive or XT versions of chips?

Tags: maximum-ratings, chip-design

I'm interested in what design changes are required to support wildly different temperature tolerances. Take for example the following 3 chips:

[image]

Nearly identical in form and function, package design, and performance, but one chip has an operating range of -55°C-125°C and another 0°C-70°C.

What changes does a manufacturer make to support these modified temperature ranges?

Derated MTBF? Different bonding wire materials? Or is the die design different entirely?

Comment: Might just be binning.

Comment: Does this partially address your question? [Why is the temperature range of industrial and military products so high?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/236850/why-is-the-temperature-range-of-industrial-and-military-products-so-high)

Comment: @MarcusMüller No, I understand the *why* very well, the *how* is what I'm interested in.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 2):

The major difference is the moisture seal quality of a certain Sumitomo grade to freeze failures.

Baking and elevated wafer level screening is also done for high temp leakage currents.

Wafer fabrication processes and package level reliability are evaluated in a variety of ways that may include accelerated environmental test conditions.

Comment: So, if I get what you're saying... the lower temperature range is a moisture seal (I assume around the edges of the chip). I suppose that plays into the maximum RH throughout the temperature range... The upper end of the temperature range is still a little unclear to me... are you saying that it's the exact same die, but the quality of the wafer is higher and possibly processed differently? I understand the evaluation/testing side, I'm still not clear on what exactly changes to make it higher tolerance operating temps?

Comment: The wide temp requires more analog margin, moisture proof seals were once ceramic only, now special plastic.